# Restarting Rails app using passenger, nginx, and centos 6.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm having some issues loading a new mailer template in my Rails app and I think I need to restart the server.  I just got my server running using Phusion Passenger with help from [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-passenger-with-nginx-on-centos-6-5) but it doesn't show how to restart the app server.  I can restart Nginx without any problems but it doesn't work with passenger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your app directory just run `touch tmp/restart.txt`. Passenger monitors that file and restarts whenever touched.

You can verify your server restarted with `passenger-status` - the Uptime field should show you it just restarted.

Comment: I'm checking the status, it doesn't show a successful restart.  Is there another way?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment.  Apparently it just didn't work right away.